# MySQL optional filters for search query

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I am working on a query that has an optional filter, so lets assume the table name is products and the filter is the id (primary key)

If the filter is not present I would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products;
```

If the filter is present I would need to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?;
```

I have found some potential solutions that can mix the 2 in sql rather than doing conditions in the back-end code itself

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = IF(? = '', id, ?);
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE IF(? = '',1, id = ?);
```

I was just wondering which one would be faster (In the case of multiple filters or a very big table) Or is there a better solution to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach is `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE (? IS NULL OR id = ?);
```

Please note that as you will add more and more conditions with `AND`, generated plan will be at least poor. There is no fit-them-all solution. If possible you should build your query using conditional logic.

More info: [The “Kitchen Sink” Procedure (SQL Server - but idea is the same)](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: Is that faster compared to the 2 approaches I have listed? I always thought "OR" isn't always the fastest.

Comment: @RMT Faster is relative.  Expression like `IF(? = '',1, id = ?);` will not utilize index if exist on column id. Please do  research with `explain` and compare execution plans for both.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to construct the `WHERE` clause from the parameters available.  This allows the Optimizer to do a much better job.

```
$wheres = array();

// Add on each filter that the user specified:
if (! empty($col))     { $s = $db->db_res->real_escape_string($col);
                                       $wheres[] = "collection = '$s'"; }
if (! empty($theme))   { $s = $db->db_res->real_escape_string($theme);
                                       $wheres[] = "theme = '$s'"; }
if (! empty($city))    { $s = $db->db_res->real_escape_string($city);
                                       $wheres[] = "city = '$s'"; }
if (! empty($tripday)) { $s = $db->db_res->real_escape_string($tripday);
                                       $wheres[] = "tripday = '$s'"; }

// Prefix with WHERE (unless nothing specified):
$where = empty($wheres) ? '' :
            'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $wheres);

// Use the WHERE clause in the query:
$sql = "SELECT ...
           $where
           ...";
```